# Activate Full Screen when entering/refreshing page

Tags: html, fullscreen

I have a slider project that needs full screen to work on a smart tv.
There is a button with `onClick="requestFullScreen"`, but every time i need to update the page on Github, i need to refresh the screen and click the button.

So i thought, there is a way to refresh automatically using: `<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='seconds'>`.

But how can i activate full screen when entering/refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event to run some code whenever the page is loading (which will also trigger when you refresh the page).
Example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working, getting Permission check failed error